# Can't trigger ASP Controller from react with fetch

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-core, controller

I try to trigger a ASP Controller from React. I tested many different things.But nothing works.
Sometimes I get the message in browser that routes does not exist (I try many routes) or "No routes matched location "/DataController/alldata". The last time I get the message "Enable to verify the first certificate".(From Postman)

The current code:

ASP Controller

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class DataController : Controller {
...


[HttpGet]
[Route("alldata")]
public IActionResult GetData(){
var data = new {key1="test1", key2="test2"};
return Ok(data)
}
```

React Code (fetch)

```
export const GetDataset = function () {
const fetchData = async() => {
try {
 const result = await fetch('https://localhost:port/DataController/alldata')
 const jTest = await result.json();
 
}catch(error){
.....
}
}
fetchData()
}
```

React Component Call

```
componentDidMount() {
 GetDataset();
}
```

Comment: Try to share the Startup.cs / Program.cs to see how is your pipeline looks like.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `[controller]` in the route, that means the name of the controller class *minus the word Controller*.

So your URL should be something like: `https://localhost:port/Data/alldata`.

Comment: Thanks. I tested this already. But that was not the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this to your program.cs file:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Note that it has to be in that order.

Comment: This is already defined in program.cs. It's really horrible. For now I think I have the right route. But I get always 404. And I don't know why. Nothing in browser. nothing in ASP App.

Comment: Go back again with setting up API, you probably missed something, like one line of code or not sending headers and those stuff

Answer (score 0):

> I tested many different things.But nothing works. Sometimes I get the
> message in browser that routes does not exist (I try many routes) or
> "No routes matched location "/DataController/alldata".

Well, based on your shared code snippet and description, I have tried to reproduce your issue, and was I able to hit the controller endpoint and got the response accordingly.

Altough, your code seems alright and I have just omitted the `[Authorize]` because I don't need that in order to execute my testing scenario. Its working accordingly.

Here is the steps I did, for calling he API from the react endpoint:

Controller:

Almost same as yours:

```
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DataController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("alldata")]
        public IActionResult GetData()
       {
            var data = new { key1 = "test1", key2 = "test2" };
            return Ok(data);
        }
    
    }
```

Program.cs file:

In the program.cs file I have configured the CORS setting:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin",
        builder => builder.WithOrigins("YourReactEndpoint")
                          .AllowAnyHeader()
                          .AllowAnyMethod());
});

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

React Testing Code:

I have used below approach in react for quick test:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://localhost:7299/Data/alldata');
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }
      const result = await response.json();
      console.log(result);
      setData(result);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
    }
  };

  fetchData();
}, []);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
     
    </div>
  );
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this example](https://playcode.io/1708711) in case of your reference.